# Django get_queryset method of a custom model manager has no effect on other built-in methods(get, filter, etc.)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have created a model manager with a method that adds some string to the certain field and my goal is to apply this method every time when `objects` called. As I understand, this can be achieved by using the `get_queryset` method in the custom manager, however this only works if I call `SomeModel.objects.all()`. If I try to apply some filter, or get object by parametr, it simply returns me original data without my method applied.

*models.py:*

```
class BaseModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def edit_desc(self, string):
        if self.exists():
            for obj in self:
                if 'description' in obj.__dict__:
                    obj.__dict__['description'] += string
        return self


class BaseModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return BaseModelQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).edit_desc('...')


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    objects = BaseModelManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

*Output in django shell:*

```
>>> SomeModel.objects.all()[0].description
    'Some example of description...'
>>> SomeModel.objects.get(id=1).description
    'Some example of description'
```

People, what am I doing wrong, please help. Thanks thousand times in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `model.objects.get` method does not return a QuerySet, so the call is never handled by `get_queryset`. `.get` returns a single object, not an iterable of objects.

Therefore, you want to override the `get` method in your model manager to specially handle the case for `.get`.

Comment: hi Moses, thanks a lot for your reply, I am wondering if there is any possibility not to override every method I want to use, but inherit functionality instead. I know this could sound weird, but is there is only possible solution is to rewrite each method?

Comment: @Michael Don't see how you can change the respective behaviours without addressing each method.

Comment: that sounds very sadly, I thought all functionality is inherited when I set models.QuerySet as a parent class and only for specific cases there is need to rewrite methods.

Comment: All methods that return a QuerySet (`all`, `filter`, `exclude` etc.) should work with your code. You need to handle others that don't return Query sets explicitly.

Comment: ok, now its getting more complicated for me, because filter and exclude dont work as well

Comment: >>> SomeModel.objects.filter(id=1)[0].description                                                      >>> Some example of description'

Comment: Try assigning the model manager in the class inheriting the base class instead of the base class itself.

Comment: same, unfortunatelly